# Can we track average age of users from a particular channel using Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am using the `Google Analytics Referrer` to track the channel of my downloads. Now what I want to do is analyse the quality of users we are getting from each channel, so that we can focus more on channels which give us better quality users. For starting I want to track something which is like `Average age of users from channel A (Month Wise)`. Does google analytics gives you the provision of analysing this type of data given we will pass the age of each user to GA. If not google analytics, what could be other tools I can use for the same. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screen shot]

It's so easy. Open channels report and add second dimension - Age. That's all.